# JSON strigify is not giving me the full object angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to send a json via http.post but it's not sending correctly, I mean the name of class is not put as a json key, this is my object :

```
export class DeviceInfo {
    deviceId: string;
    deviceType: string;
    notificationToken: string;
}
```

And I want to send

```
{
"deviceInfo": {
    "deviceId":"123",
    "deviceType":"DEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID",
    "notificationToken":"123"   
}
}
```

But is sending only :

```
{
    "deviceId":"123",
    "deviceType":"DEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID",
    "notificationToken":"123"   
}
```

How do I send the full object as a JSON?

Comment: That IS full object. Class name doesn't mean anything nor should it be used as an identifier since it can be minified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it like:

```
tostring(device:DeviceInfo) {
    return JSON.stringify({deviceInfo:device});
}
```

or

```
        const de = new DeviceInfo();
        const className = de.constructor.name;
        const obj = {};
        obj[className] = de;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create another request object which you can send.

```js
export class MyRequest {
    deviceInfo: DeviceInfo;
}
```

The result of `JSON.stringify(myRequest);` then is what you want:

```
{
    "deviceInfo": {
        "deviceId":"123",
        "deviceType":"DEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID",
        "notificationToken":"123"   
    }
}
```